# laplace transform of unit step function $u(t+1)$

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

what is the laplace transform of unit step function $u(t+1)$?According to my understanding it should be $ e^s/s$ but I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 2):

When you have doubt , you can always use the integral definition of the Laplace Transform:
$$f(s)=\int_0^\infty u(t+1)e^{-st}dt$$
$$f(s)=\int_{-1}^\infty e^{-st}dt$$
$$f(s)=\dfrac {e^{-st}}{-s}\bigg|_{-1}^\infty$$
$$f(s)=\dfrac {e^{s}}{s}$$
So yes you're right.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed. More generally,

$$\mathcal{L}(u(t-a)) = \frac{e^{-as}}{s}$$

Take $a=-1$ for your desired transform. A number of identities such as this can be found on [this page I have bookmarked](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf).