# Laplace Transform Unit Step Function

Tags: laplace-transform

I was wondering what is meant by a unit step function in Laplace transform diff equations. Eg : $f''(t) + bf'(t) + cf(t) = u(t)?$ I know that $L[f''(t)]$ is $s^2F(s)-sf(0)-f'(0)$ and so on, but what to do with $u(t)?$

Comment: Assuming $u(t) = 1$ for $t \geq 0$ and $0$ for $t < 0$, or something similar, plug this into the definition of the Laplace transform and compute!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laplace transform of unit step function $u(t+1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3542351/laplace-transform-of-unit-step-function-ut1)

Comment: If you are interested in the initial value problem for $t\geq 0$, then $u(t)\equiv 1$.